# realm mobile platform sync and web app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm, electron, realm-mobile-platform

I'm looking at using realm for a project I'm working on which will be a multi-platform mobile app which will needs to sync data between users / devices. I think the realm mobile platform would be perfect.

However, I also need to have a admin / web app. I've seen that realm has a react-native module so I can use react-native to create my mobile app. Question is can I also use react (or react-native) to create a web admin app or even a desktop version using Electron?!.. In effect the admin app syncs to the same realm the mobile app is using via the realm mobile platform.

Hope that makes sense - Thanks is advance..

Comment: Depends on what the admin wants to do. The admin/webapp would most definitely require the Enterprise license to do what you want - the RMP dev license allows you to run a ROS that synchronizes all Realms that belong to a given user, but provides no means of tinkering with this data apart from the ROS Dashboard and the Realm Browser.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:
The new [Professional Edition](https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm-mobile-platform-professional-edition/) might be the solution you are looking for.

---

<strike>As EpicPandaForce states, you would need the enterprise license in order to use sync on the server.</strike>

There is a Node SDK for Realm: https://realm.io/news/first-object-database-realm-node-js-server/. We are not officially supporting Electron yet though people have managed to make it work. However, that doesn't yet offer sync so it won't help you in this particular case but stay tuned for updates on that situation!